# Find pattern for certain classes failing to appear

Tags: html, css, hosting

Here is the site I'm building:

http://www.littlefishlighting.com/LFL.html

Using dev tools it seems clear that the css file is linked. Most classes/ids are working perfectly. But certain key classes and all their decendents are failing to appear(e.g .menuWrapper, .footer). Though the class is present in both the .css file and the .html file it is just completely missing -- not being overridden.

After running both the html file and the css through some verifiers, there are no errors that reveal the pattern with the failing classes.

All browsers are having the same issue.

Comment: You have linked your CSS correctly, and used the correct names for your classes. The selectors are not even getting overridden by higher specificity. Typically this is caused by a missing end bracket in the previous declaration, but those are fine too. Strange. However, you have  [**a few other errors in your CSS**](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.littlefishlighting.com%2FLFL.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en), as revealed by W3C. Try correcting those, and see if the problem resolves.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of carriage returns in your `background` css rules that are breaking the stylesheet. Here are a few examples

```
#interiorImg {
    background:url('
http://www.littlefishlighting.com/LFL-images/UTNeylundStadium/102.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    background-size: cover;
}

#artImg {
    background:url('
http://www.littlefishlighting.com/LFL-portfolio-outdoor.html') no-repeat center center; 
    background-size: cover;
}

#exteriorImg {
    background:url('
http://www.littlefishlighting.com/LFL-images/ElectricWarfBridge/101.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

What validator did you use? the w3c css validator shows errors. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.littlefishlighting.com%2FLFL.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

I removed the carriage returns and fixed the errors from the validator - this look better? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/dRpPpP

Answer (score 0):

LESSON: If things are strange with stylesheet, make sure all css is up to spec.

My relatively small errors in CSS were causing weird things to happen. I knew of those errors from the validator, but didn't realize it could cause this kind of odd failure.

This is probably a "duh" for veterans, but I was so focused on trying to figure out a pattern that I wasn't looking at these somewhat unrelated issues.

Thanks for the quick replies. Its crunch time and this is (unsurprisingly) one of my first projects.